# Python Request and simplejson how to acces keyvalue

Tags: python, request, simplejson

I have a problem. I try to get data from json file:
task is:
Complete the function get_post_body so that it returns the content of the post

```
data = requests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
data.json(userId, id, title, body)


def get_post_body(post_id):
    return data['body']
```

Comment: May I know what is the problem?

Comment: i try to take data from json file on return data['body']

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you need.

```
import requests

data = requests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
data = data.json()
for i in data:
    print(i["body"])
    print(i["userId"])
    print(i["id"])
```

Comment: i need script what is ask for id like raw_input(int) to take id and for this id take body and give data on data return  i try this but its not work                                              data = requests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
data = data.json()
int(post_id) = raw_input(int)
def get_post_body(post_id):

    return data['body']